# How to remove Css class from a tag with the same css already present in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

First of all, sorry if the question didnt make much sense. Finding it hard to frame the question properly but this is what I am trying to do.

**Current Behaviour**
Able to toggle the css class between the two **h1** tags but unable to toggle after enabling toggle; meaning unable to remove css class on the `h1` tag where css class is already enabled.

**Intended Behaviour**
On click of the same active `h1`, it should remove the css class.

Link to the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/615abd817f414715946d384fe01f668c?version=3.29.7), also the same code below.

App

```
<script>
    import Component2 from './Component2.svelte'
    let numbers = [1,2];
    let selectedOption;
    const runThis = (i) => {
        selectedOption = i;
    }
</script>

{#each numbers as number}
    <Component2 isSelected={selectedOption === number} {number} on:click={()=>runThis(number)}/>
{/each}
```

Component.svelte

```
<script>
    export let number;
    export let isSelected;
</script>

<h1 on:click class:red={isSelected}>Hello {number}</h1>

<style>
    .red{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue by toggling is that you have to be sure that the new selected number isn't the one already selected. So if the current `selectedOption` is the same as `i`, just set it to `null`:

```js
const runThis = (i) => {
    selectedOption = i !== selectedOption ? i : null;
}
```

See the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/450be342581a4367b2b27fc43e787946?version=3.29.7).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
    import Component from './Component.svelte'
    let numbers = [1,2];
    let selectedOption;
    const runThis = (i) => {
        if(selectedOption===i)
            selectedOption=-1
        else
           selectedOption = i;
    }
</script>

{#each numbers as number}
    <Component isSelected={selectedOption === number} {number} on:click={()=>runThis(number)}/>
{/each}
```

**Component.svelte**

```
//same
```